# FB api - post an image on someone else public page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to do a post on a public page not mine...I'm using this code:

```
FB.api(
 "/https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXX/feed",
 "POST",
{
    "message": "This is a test message"
    },
    function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log('riuscito:'+response);
        } else {
            console.log('fallito:'+JSON.stringify(response.error));
      }
    }
);
```

where "/https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXX/feed", is the facebook public page.
I Logging into facebook with my user and this code it's ok, but I received an error like this:
fallito:{"message":"(#210) A page access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":210}

How can I get the page access token from https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXX/feed when this page is not mine?
Is it possible?
thank you
Carlo

Answer (score 1):

You can´t get a Page Token for a Page you don´t own.

You can only try to use a User Token, but your API call is wrong:

```
FB.api(
   "XXXXXX/feed",
   ...
```